# VS.NET git new experience

Tags: c#, vb.net, git, visual-studio

VS.NET has a new GIT experience.

In the previous version, I could do a secondary click on any local branch a choose "Merge from...", but in this new GIT Experience, the option doesn't appear.

Previous GIT Experience:

[image]

New GIT Experience:

[image]

How can I do a "merge from" in this new GIT experience?

Comment: The mix of enabled/disabled items shown on your "new experience" menu look consistent with what you see if you right click on the *current* branch, where it obviously doesn't make sense to Checkout, Merge, etc.

Comment: It takes some time to get used to, especially if you've been using the old way for a long time. From my memory, you should be able to do the same thing by clicking on the branch name on top of the Git Changes window and find your target branch. Whilst on the dropdown, right click on that branch and select merge from option. It should be somewhere around there. I'll post an answer when I'm home :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MichaelWayne. I could do it!

Comment: Cool! Added it as an answer so others looking for it can find it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to merge from action by clicking on the branch name on top of the Git Changes window, right clicking on the branch you want to merge from and select Merge from option.

Alternatively, same thing can be done on the branches / commit history window. Again, right click on the branch you want to merge from (on the left this time) and do the same steps as usual.

[image: Image from a Microsoft DevBlog titled 'Announcing the Release of the Git Experience in Visual Studio]